# I found an interesting question but I keep getting stuck in a loop.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Find all values of A, B, C and C such that:
$$
\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x+2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2}
$$

I keep getting into a loop in which:
$$
x - 1 = Ax^2 - 4Ax + 4A + Bx^2 - Bx - 2B + Cx + C
$$

Which then creates a system which will create equal versions of existing equations in the system.
$$
-1 = 4A - 3B + C
$$
$$
-1 = -Ax - Bc + 4A + B - C
$$

Are there any methods of approaching this?

Comment: Isn’t it just $A=B=0$, $C=1$ by looking at it?

Comment: You could say that, but I can not conclude with a solution before going through an algebraic process.

Comment: The tag `linear-algebra` is your hint.  This is a system of linear equations.  They should not have $x$ in them! Your linear algebra text should cover those solution methods [perhaps called "Gaussian elimination" or "echelon form"]  Don't forget the equation for the coefficient of $x^2$, namely $A+B=0$.

Comment: Were you first multiplying both sides by $(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)(x-2)^2$?

Comment: A, B, C and C?  Could you also check the signs as if this is an exercise in partial fractions, something like $\frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-2)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x-2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2}$ might be a more typical set up

Comment: @Durian: Why did you not cancel  $(x-1)$ in num/den ?

Comment: Your system of equations looks totally wrong, based on the previous line. Also you replace $x+1$ with $x-1$ and $x-2$ with $x+2$. I'd try redoing this whole thing.

Comment: The domains of the left- and right-hand sides are different.

Comment: You got into the "*loop*": $x-1 = A(x-2)^2 + B(x-2)(x+1) + C(x+1)$, but how?

Answer (score 1):

**Mistake in The Problem / Your Post**

First, there are mistakes in the decomposition. The proper equation should be:

$$
\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x-2)^{2}}
=
\frac{A}{x-1}+
\frac{B}{x-2}+
\frac{C}{(x-2)^{2}}
$$

from which we have

$$
\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x-2)^{2}}
=
\frac{A(x-2)^{2}+B(x-1)(x-2)+C(x-1)}{(x-1)(x-2)^{2}}
$$

**Comparing The Numerators**

Because the denominators on the LHS and RHS are equal, the numerators must be equal as well:

$$
x-1
=
(A+B)x^{2}+(-4A-3B+C)x+(4A+2B-C)
$$

which can be written in matrix-vector notations:

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
x^{2} \\ x \\ 1
\end{Bmatrix}^{\top}
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ -1
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{Bmatrix}
x^{2} \\ x \\ 1
\end{Bmatrix}^{\top}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & -3 & 1 \\
4 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
A \\ B \\ C
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

and the solution is

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
A \\ B \\ C
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & -3 & 1 \\
4 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ -1
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

i.e. $A=B=0$ and $C=1$

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view like below:
$$* \ \ \frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-2)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x-2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2}$$
multilply * by $(x+1)$ then put $x=-1$ $$(x+1) \times (\frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-2)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x-2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2}) \\ \frac{x-1}{(x-2)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{1} + (x+1)(\frac{B}{x-2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2}) \\x=-1 \to \frac {-1-1}{(-1-2)^2}=A+0 \to A=\frac {-2}{9}$$
then multiply * by $(x-2)^2$ to finc $C$
$$(x-2)^2(\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x+2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2})\\\frac {x-1}{x+1}=(x-2)^2(\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x-2})+C \\x=2 \to \frac {2-1}{2+1}=0+C$$now to find B you can put any $x\neq -1,2$ forexample $x=0$
$$\frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-2)(x-2)} = \frac{\frac {-2}{9}}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x-2} + \frac{\frac {1}{3}}{(x-2)^2} \\x=0 \to \frac {0-1}{(0+1)(0-2)^2}=\frac{\frac {-2}{9}}{0+1} + \frac{B}{0-2} + \frac{\frac {1}{3}}{(0-2)^2}$$